# ssh remote login to server using system(char * command), and excute commands?

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, system

Someone familiar with [SSH](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html) and [System(const char * command)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) to execute shell command!??

Am trying to remotely login to multiple servers/machines from my C++ code, and i have to execute some commands remotely. To the best of my experience, i decided to use ssh. But, now i want to load and send all my commands through the [System(const char * command)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). pls see my code below..

```
#include "all my headers"
int main()
{
   system("ssh 172.10.10.1");//login to server_one, password=123
   system("ssh 172.10.10.2");//login to server_two, password=1234
   system("ssh 172.10.10.3");//login to server_three,password=12345
   system("ssh 172.10.10.4");//login to server_four, password=123456
  return 0;
}
```

Now,my Question is:

1. can i load and send the remote_ip of the servers and password at the
   same time, something like: `system("ssh 172.10.10.4 ,123456")`
   password=123456? if yes, how?
2. if am done with (1) above, i will have another question. thanks.

Comment: Hardcoding passwords like this is a bad idea.  You should look into using public/private keys if you're really sure that you want to do something in this way.

Comment: The [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function simply uses the shell to execute the commands. So if you can get it to work from the normal shell command prompt *without needing any input*, then you can easily make it work inside you program using `system`.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: i know it risky to send passwords in plain, but it is just for testing and security is not my issue. thanks.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: of course i can login from "normal shell command prompt", but can i send like this: [oracle@localhost Desktop]$ ssh 172.10.10.2  password ? from cmd prompt? thanks.

Comment: I know it's not what you asked, but you would probably be way, way better off writing a shell script that used "Parallel SSH."

Comment: And you're not sending them in the clear.  You're storing them in your code in the clear and potentially sending them on the command line in the clear, making them visible to anyone who can view the process table.

Comment: That's why I emphasized *"without needing any input"*. Learn more about SSH and how it works, and public versus private keys and how to use them.

Comment: You really want to write a bourne shell script instead of doing this in C.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `system("ssh ...")` will ONLY work if you have set up public keys for the machine you want to log in on.

The reason is that the `system()` does not allow you to interact with the process you started, it will just spawn a new shell and pass the relevant string to the shell for execution, and `ssh` does not itself have a way to pass the password to the application, you have to actually type it in (or send it to the stdin side of `ssh` if you use `popen` - but I would really suggest that public keys are the right way to go in an automated system).

If you still need to interact with the created process, you will need to use something like `popen`, which will allow you to read `stdout` or write to `stdin` on the  - or even `pipe()` and `fork()` if you need the ability to do stuff to both `stdin` and `stdout`.